# Java - How to use jsoup to retrieve text from tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have this HTML file and I want to retrieve the text between two tags. But also get the text in the following tags.

For example:

```
<font class="classname">Some Text Here</font>
<font class="classname">Some More Text Here</font>
<font class="classname">Even Some More Text Here</font>
```

How can I use JSOUP to read the HTML file, retrieve just the plain "Some Text Here" text, and add it to a variable?

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks and hope to get some answers!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Their documentation is fairly extensive; they have examples of reading from files and reading the text nodes from a document.

Comment: I have tried just about everything. I tried element.classname(), getElementsByClass, getElementById, getElementsByAttribute. None of these seem to work for me. I have the java code to read from file already, I just need to retrieve the information I need. @Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on comment.**

This program will iterate through all files in the folder and subfolder and change the title to the value of first `<font class="classname">`. Please not that it wont check for html files. It'll read all files considering that as an html file. If you want to filter out just html files from this folder you could use filet filters. Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class HtmlParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        modifyTitleForAllFilesInFolder(new File("c:/Test"));
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static void modifyTitleForAllFilesInFolder(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                modifyTitleForAllFilesInFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                modifyFile(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void modifyFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            File input = new File(fileName);
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
            String newTitle = doc.select("font.classname").first().text();
            doc.title(newTitle);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(input,"UTF-8");
            writer.write(doc.html());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How would the program know where the file is?

Comment: It depends on how you execute the Java code. If the file is in the execution context the you could directly give the file name as in the example.

Comment: The file part is independent of jsoup. It is pure Java code. Simply you could give absolute path as `new File("c:/myfiles/test.html")` or if its in the class folder you could use class loader as `new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.html").getPath())`

Comment: What would I do with the String html = "<font class='classname'>Some Text Here</font>"; code?

Comment: That was just an example to show how to parse you html. Please tell me your actual requirement. I could modify accordingly. Do you want the program to read an html file and get you the value?

Comment: I want the program to read from a directory of HTML files, change the title of page to <font class='classname'>Some Text Here</font> text.

Comment: Sorry, change title to "Some Text Here"

Comment: Sorry a quick clarification. You'll provide a folder with multiple html files and the program should read those one by one and change the title value to "Some Text Here". Is that so?

Comment: Also, the classname appears multiple times throughout the html files. I want the first <div><font class="classname"> that occurs on the page.

Comment: change the title value of each file to the specific "Some Text Here" of each individual HTML file